# Android notify every time the value on Retrofit call changes

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

As is title I want to be able to notify me every time the value of Retrofit call changes. Is that possible with calling this code only once in `onCreate()`? The scenario is like this. I build an RPG game. For example want to be notified about amount of gold for specific user at application start (this works). Then user kills a monster and gain some coins (another Retrofit call is made) so amount of gold on server changes and now I want to be also notified (here is where it doesn't work).

ApiInterface:

```
@GET("/getGold")
Observable<String> getGold(@Query("name") String name);
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

(...)

Api.getClient1Or2().getGold("Admin")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(string -> Log.d("string", string));
}
```

How to modify this code then?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may want to look into using WebSockets so the server can push changes. Using rest like this you have poll changes making a whole bunch of request to the GET endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `getGold` is `Observable`, it will run request only once and emit a single item.

You need to either receive `Gold` from your `WebSocket` message (preferred), or use `WebSocket` message as a trigger to refresh `Gold` by subscribing to `getGold` again (not preferred because you can send your `Gold` directly in your `WebSocket` message).

Of course, you would need your backend to expose a `WebSocket` endpoint for you with the contract for constantly updating your `Gold`.

You could also use push notification as a trigger for a refresh, but they have quotas and they are built on WebSockets anyway.